# Shared Cooldown between multiple commands in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Assume the following scenario:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents, guilds=True)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(name="command1", description="1st Command")
async def command1(interaction):
  # Command 1 Things


@tree.command(name="command2", description="2nd Command")
async def command2(interaction):
  # Command 2 Things
```

Is there a way to have a shared cooldown system so that when command1 is executed, both command1 and command2 will be on cooldown?

While `@app_commands.Cooldown()` works, it only applies that cooldown for that specific command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
cooldown = app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 1, lambda i: i.user.id)

@tree.command(name="command1", description="1st Command")
@cooldown
async def command1(interaction):
  # Command 1 Things


@tree.command(name="command2", description="2nd Command")
@cooldown
async def command2(interaction):
  # Command 2 Things
```